# How can I create a shiny metallic plastic-looking material?

Tags: materials

My first post here.  I apologize in advance for my ignorance.  I'm looking to create a material (and lighting to make it look right) that will look like the one below.. maybe a bit more metallic.  I am a complete noob when it comes to materials and light so I don't even know where to begin.  Help???

I'm using cycles render mode.

[image: Sonic Screwdriver]

Comment: Materials and Light were mentioned.
It probably more acceptable to bring up the topics separately for more focused help.
Consider searching this site for Cycles Metal.
Consider searching this site for Cycles Lights.

Comment: same as here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/make-a-gold-reflective-object but keep the color white and increase the roughness

Comment: I think you sould start by reading this page: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders Maybe a mix of glossy and inisotropic shaders is what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use a white glossy shader with a bit of roughness, and an HDRI image for the lightning.

[image]

Blender file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31926

Comment: Your file seems to have disappeared! Could you reupload it here, where it won't be deleted? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Here a metallic plastic looking material which is a plastic painted with metallic paint.  Is in fact a gloss mixed with diffuse and on top of that you use a reflection layer. Reflection layer is a colorless gloss with Fresnel. If you want to make it more metallic, slide the mix shader to the right. You can unplug the RGB node and give the first two nodes the same color or your choice.  [image: Node setup of plastic with metallic paint]

Answer (score 0):

This is a better answer to your dilemma.

There is a tutorial on the "Blender Guru" Andrew Price's website on how to make a node group for PBR Dielectrics such as plastic,fabric and/or brick and a node group for PBR Metal.

I can give you the link:https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/pbr-shader-tutorial-pt1/