# Simplest way to create a database symbol

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a database symbol like this

[image]

The only way I currently know how to do this is by starting with a flat cylinder and repeatedly extruding and scaling.

extrude
scale Z
scale .9
extrude
scale Z
scale 1.1

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is very tedious. How else could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a single piece out of a cylinder.

To make the edges less sharp read this question:

[Weird deformation between large ngon and edge ring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3199/weird-deformation-between-large-ngon-and-edge-ring/3204#3204)

[image]

[image]

Add an array modifier, and move the relative offset values for the Z axis like this.

[image]

[image]

Add a mix of glossy and anisotropic shaders.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT** Want an even simpler way?

Add a Curve->Circle.

[image]

[image]

Make it a 2D curve, fill in on both sides, give it some extrusion and bevel:

[image]

[image]

Add the array modifier, and texture.

For Info on how light a shiny object read this: [Make a gold reflective object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/make-a-gold-reflective-object/15685#15685)

Comment: That works perfectly. How did you get such uniform lighting over the object?

Comment: For the lighiting you just need a big source. Either a large plane or something like this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15685/1853