# Cycles advanced shader ball?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

Is there an official cycles material preview ball to compare the shader with 100% white? I could only find the following image [here](https://davidzerba.wordpress.com/2012/12/17/cycles-shaders/). Except of the inner material this looks like what I'm looking for:

[image]

*Image by David Zerba*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Blender Material Preview Scene (BMPS) was included in the 2.61 demo files, which you can download here:

[Blender 2.61 demo files: Cycles & Dynamic Paint](http://archive.blender.org/development/release-logs/blender-261/blender-261-demo-files/index.html)

Just open the bmps.blend file to find the material shader ball scene.

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: The `bmps.blend` file has been around for a long time (added in 2011) but they deleted it just recently (Dec 14, 2022). The last version can be found here: [blender-3.4-release/lib/tests/cycles/](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/tags/blender-3.4-release/lib/tests/cycles/)

Answer (score 9):

There is also a material preview scene provided by [blenderdiplom.com](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/) with a better light setup:

[image]

http://blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/584-download-cycles-material-test-scene.html

Answer (score 0):

For reference: Blender 2.81+ includes the shader ball as part of the *material* preview, so you do not need to download the .blend for it. It is extremely helpful, (and quite realistic too), for showing materials.

Comment: Cool, just found the patch: https://developer.blender.org/T57683. However, not that helpful for serious lookdev due to bad lighting and a too small preview.