# How do I create a reflective white material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I'm pretty new to this and this is my first question here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

So basically what I want to achieve is a floor material as seen in this photo...

[image]

...the reflections are very crisp but dim.

With a glossy shader I get the following results:

[image]

First picture: reflections are blurry

Second picture: roughness of the material looks right but reflection is bright red

Third picture: If tinted in any other color than white, it seems to produce the result I want. Reflection is sharp **and** gets tinted blue. What I need is the reflection to be tinted white.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The key is to mix a glossy shader with a diffuse.

[image]

The lower the *fac* on the mix shader the more of the first input (in this case more glossiness). For more realism, you can feed fresnel values to the *fac* input, or you can mix it with non-glossy parts with this (i.e. if you are making puddles).

Comment: Thanks so much! I knew I was missing something simple. Looks like I wanted it.

Comment: If you feed fresnel values like you suggest you will have to invert them or switch the shaders in the mix node.

Answer (score 46):

The floor is actually more reflective near the horizon. This effect is called Fresnel and it adds a lot of realism into the scene.

Your shader should look like this:

[image]

Instead of controlling the amount of reflection with the *Mix Shader* Fac input, you control the amount with the value of color of the *Glossy node*. Black will be no reflection.

As the roughness is 0, this is a **PBR dielectric shader**. If the roughness would be more than 0, the *Fresnel node* would have to be [upgraded to account for the roughness](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63773/metal-material-with-glass-and-gloss-node/63779#63779).

To keep it physically correct, keep the color of the Glossy node white. You adjust the color of the floor with the *Diffuse shader*.

Here is a comparison between this setup with Fresnel (left) and not physically correct setup with just mixed diffuse and glossy (right):

[image]

The right ball should feel un-natural.

Comment: Nice answer Jerryno! I am so excited about Blender's PBR rendering possibilities right now. I think we'll need to add a new PBR tag here in Blender Stack.

Comment: +1 I had to join this exchange just to upvote this answer, I never knew blender had this much flexibility built in.

Comment: Nice answer, however, a link, or instructions, on how to adjust the Fresnel node to be more accurate based on roughness would be nice.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms True, I should link it back with this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63779/7777 (it's only linked from there here) as it contains the rough fresnel

Comment: This should be marked as the best answer.

Answer (score 8):

To get a more realistic material, add distorted noise to the displacement node. You will get a very similar surface to the one in the photo.

[image: Node example]

Answer (score 4):

Try to mix glossy shader with diffuse shader. Both white. It makes kind of a ceramic texture. Use the mix shader for this. Play with the mix value and the roughness value of the glossy shader to achieve the look you want.