# Tinted reflections and specular light manipulation

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am coming from the Lightwave. So far, I like the Blender. Especially, some of the modelling tools. Cycles is nice too, but I have two problems, ergo two questions.

How to manipulate the specular light (size, color, and intensity), and how to make strong and sharp colour tinted reflections (like the christmas ornaments)?

Here I have a cup, it has a not too strong, but a sharp reflection ("medium" tinted), with a strong, intensive and sharp, white coloured specular light.

If I make my object more reflective in Blender, the reflection of the environment is washing out the colours from my texture. I attached an extreme (ugly ) Lightwave render. You see that the textured spheres have a colour tinted, sharp and strong reflection, with a white specular.

Can I do this with Cycles? I know that this looks not realistic, but renderers are not just about realism. Futuristic sci-fi materials, or some artistic works need to go outside the PBR dimension.

So, is it possible to render the same picture with Cycles? If yes, how?

Thank you for reading, and have a nice life!

The image on the bottom is Cycles render. You can see that the cup is too soft.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62568/how-do-i-create-a-reflective-white-material Also keep only one question per post, post as many as needed.

Comment: Generally speaking you start by mixing a *Glossy* and *Diffuse* shader, then control reflection color from the color of a *Glossy* shader, the amount of reflection with the *Mix* shader node, and the color of the material with the *Diffuse* shader.

Comment: Hi! Ok I will post one question at once (In lightwave this two things are grown together). The link you was giving, is about a one colour reflective material, in a one colour environment. I know the basic mixings of materials. It don'helps. If I mix more glossy, then the cup's colours are too radicaly changing. For example, you will see the plate's texture in fine sharp blue color on the red guy. In reality, the reflection should be more red then blue (like in the christmas ornament). Again: I want to now how to render the image with two spheres in cycles.There is the essence of my question.

Comment: I can make more tinted reflections in cycles, but then the reflections do not have enough strongness-sharpness.

Comment: (ex lighwave user here...) To help you better please include an image of your current material nodes, render and colour management settings. Specular reflections are controlled by the roughness value on the glossy shader. It seems to me that to get the bright highlights you are looking for you need to increase the brightness of the light source that is causing them. Bright speculars require bright sources and such scene could also benefit from the use of a wide dynamic range. Try using "filmic" blender and PR shaders.

Comment: Thank you Duarte and cegaton for the replies. cegaton! Okay. Tomorrow I will try to make the above two spheres (or very similar) image in cycles. I am sure if i can do that, my problem is solved. I know that I can't. And I will send the screencapcha from my nodes. The scene with the cup is a experimental ground, without cleaning for a long time. To understand: A hyper mess of nodes. I want to start learn all this glossy stuff from the basics. So, the spheres and nodes are coming in the next 1-2 days (depending from my job times). Again: Thanx!