# How do I make a surface look like a polished one in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

I am making some spheres like these . Hence I need a surface similar to this.[image]

Comment: very similar: [How do I create a reflective white material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/62568/2217)

Comment: Thanks  to everyone for helping me out. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This polished look can be achieved with a black diffuse shader and a white glossy shader (roughness = 0), letting a fresnel node set the mix between them using a mix shader.

[image]

[image]

Comment: One important thing to note when dealing with dark shiny objects like this is that the environment around them plays a crucial role. Realated: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/50576/1853

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a dense geometry.  A mesh with a lot of faces to blend the reflections smoothly.

Second, about the sharp reflection, you have to use a shader with gloss/roughness settings.  Set the roughness to very low, and you will have very sharp reflections.

Comment: You don't really need that many faces. Just make sure you mark them as smooth.

Comment: I don't even need to set anything to smooth if I only have 1 single face, and if I wanted a straight mirror.

Comment: Sure, but for the ball....

Answer (score -2):

Use Cycles nodes, like Glass shader, and give high IOR, like 50, for the reflections

Comment: As the result aiming to in the question most likely is intended to be realistic this won't work as IOR can't be on that value

Comment: @Mr Zak Is that so? When I give it, Blender accepts it. Try it. The default IOR is too low

Comment: The fact that Blender accepts it doesn't mean it's correct way to do this