How to make the floor more reflective and more like a wooden material
I'm new to learn texturing and lighting. I need some help on this floor.
Here's my floor 
and i want to make it like this

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93294/make-a-reflective-surface https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81691/how-do-i-make-a-surface-look-like-a-polished-one-in-blender

This question is similar to: How do I make a surface look like a polished one in Blender?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Okay, I would not look too closely on the questions linked here because they are 7 years old and one explains how to do it with the Blender Internal render engine which doesn't exist anymore, the Cycles version there explains how to make a metallic material, on the other question the accepted answer is very outdated since it is not necessary to use four nodes (Fresnel, Mix Shader, Diffuse BSDF, Glossy BSDF) which can easily be done with a single node (Principled BSDF) with even more options... the other answers there are just bad.

Another thing is, creating a reflective material is just half the solution (you don't even show your material). Your question lacks of some information, to get a "shiny" surface it is not only about the surface itself, it depends on the viewing angle and if there is something in the environment which gets reflected to make the surface appear shiny. All I see in your screenshot compared to the reference is that the viewing angle is steeper (could appear less reflective) and I see no light sources, I have no idea if there maybe is an HDRI for the world lighting which could be reflected etc.
