# how to create a shiny latex like material in blender cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm experimenting with blender cycles and there are a few things I have problems with/ I am not happy with the results.

One is creating a shiny plastic. I tried it on my own, because I found no help for this specific problem online.

My setting looks like this right now.
[image: blender cycle setting]

the blend setting in layer weight is just guessing on my part

and this is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: shiny black latex suit]

But I have no idea, how to make it better.
Hope you can help.

Comment: Your node set up looks fine, what dont you like about it?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62568/how-do-i-create-a-reflective-white-material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple one with the Principled Shader. I added some slight roughness texture for realism (Maybe it use a touch more?). Also the lighting you choose will be a HUGE factor.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the principled shader with zero roughness. The node set up you have should work just fine too. Not sure what you dont like about it.

[image]

Comment: I didn't like the highlights in my setting. but might have been lighting. and thanks for your answer