# How to make eye shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

[image]

I am trying to create a sonic model and I would like to know if anyone could help me replicate the eye material shown below. So far i’ve Tried using some glass shaders mixed with some diffuse shaders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a reflective white material?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62568/how-do-i-create-a-reflective-white-material)

Comment: rather use a mix between Diffuse and Glossy nodes

Comment: It’s similar but it’s not as reflective

Comment: This is not a duplicate of “how do I create a reflective white material”