# how can I make the color looks whiter

Tags: materials, color

[image]
I am just wondering how can I make the color whiter but also metal-like. the car model should have a white-painted metal shell. But I cannot make the color look like white. Although I put white color in there, it looks silver-like. Can anyone help me out to make this look like white-painted metal shell? Thanks.

Comment: The most important thing when dealing with reflective objects is the environment reflected on them. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48659/why-does-an-object-with-a-glossy-shader-render-in-black/50576#50576

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/62568/how-do-i-create-a-reflective-white-material