# The correct Node workflow?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I stumbled upon this link which depicts the workflow for creating materials in Houdini.

[Material Studies: Metals](https://www.behance.net/gallery/35636521/Material-Studies-Metals)

How would you approach this workflow in Blender ?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the *Principled* shader with metalness all the way to 1.0. Just input those values into it and that's all. If you want a metal shader more accurate see this: [Conductive Fresnel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76033/7777)

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will get into it! @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny

Comment: I asked about a workflow which is complex and general, i didn`t ask "how i create iron mat" so yea, uncalled for on that one. :) @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: @Occultcg There's nothing wrong with asking "how to create iron mat", or "how to replicate this workflow", but please take the time to read [the suggestions here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2450/599). Adding some description of the content of the link — or better yet, what you've tried and what hasn't worked — will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Ok i will take that into account in the future, thanks for the tips! @gandalf3