# Adding shiny gold material to a slice of bread

Tags: materials

I have a slice of bread inside a crusty loaf. Enclosed is the image (the outside crusty loaf is not shown) and the node editor.

The outside crusty loaf is completed. The problem lies only with the slice of bread, to which I wish to add shiny gold material, so that it looks as a slice of bread made of shiny gold.

I’d appreciate any advice, showing me how to do that.

Thank you,

[image: Bread image and the Node Editor]

Comment: try adding a Mix Shader and using your existing Diffuse BSDF as one input and add Glossy Shader as the other setting the colour appropriately. To get a good reflection set your background to an HDR

Comment: rob, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 2):

As a rough first shot:

- Use a tool like [Materialize](http://boundingboxsoftware.com/materialize/) to generate a pseudo-height map from
  your diffuse image of the bread
- Having UV unwrapped your slice you can use the height map to bump-map the surface of the slice using a simple set of shader nodes something like this...

[image]

Here, if the height is less than a threshold, a fully transparent material is substituted for the gold, so as to poke  holes in the bread. You might feel you need actually to [displace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/materials/displacement.html) the surface of the slice in shading, too, if your shot is close-up, or at a raking angle.

Once you've provided an HDR environment to reflect from the metal surface, you get this sort of result.

[image]

As for the metal itself, you could substitute this principled shader for something more sophisticated: from [approximating physically accurate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76033/35559) to [quite convincing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89084/35559).

Comment: Robin Betts, thanks a lot for your detailed and enlightening answer, which I followed and which yielded an excellent result. Thank you.