# What elements go into a good material testing scene

Tags: modeling, materials, light, shaders

I've been searching a bit for the perfect material testing scene, so I'm curious, what are some of the most important elements in a material testing scene?

Comment: It depends on your needs, but in general I would suggest use a **shaderball scene**: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21807/cycles-advanced-shader-ball, in use: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23913/how-to-create-a-mirror-shader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure you have correct neutral lighting (a diffuse grey (50%)
  sphere should render as diffuse grey (50%)).
- You need some reflectors to judge reflections.
- Maybe you should have an object with a stepped thickness so that you
  can see how refraction behaves.
- You could also setup additional renderlayers with different lighting
  situations.
- Maybe a grid on the floor to get the scale right (cm, dm, m)?
- A McBeth chart of some sort?
- A diffuse and a reflective sphere for reference in some corner?

I think SHED have some nice examples [in their blog somewhere](http://shedmtl.blogspot.se/)...

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. Could you be a bit more specific? Also, if you're going to link to a blog, could you link to a specific article? I just don't think it's good to link to a blog and expect someone to actually go through it to try to find something that they don't even know the name of.

Comment: So what is it then you are looking for? More specific on what? As for the blog, I just seem to remember that they show some pictures where they test their shaded models in hdri environments. Sorry I don't have the time right now to look it up for you.

Comment: I was thinking a bit more information for each of your points, but at this point I think it's good enough.