# What is this 3D Model?

Tags: modeling, materials, objects

I have come across this model many times.

[image]

I am sure that this is a very common model, however, I can not find out anything about it.  What is it, and Where can I get it?

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-shader-encyclopedia/

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21807/cycles-advanced-shader-ball

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "eye-like" logo seems to be the one from [Blenderguru](http://www.blenderguru.com/). Doing a reverse image search on Google, it seems that it has first been published by Greg Zaal for the [Cycles Shader Encyclopedia](http://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-shader-encyclopedia/).

I don't think you should use it, since the logo might be copyright protected. For blender users, the Blender ape "Suzanne" is often used for demonstration purposes. You can create it by "Add/Mesh/Monkey".

Comment: Great! This is not exactly the answer but atleast 90% of what i wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! But i only intend to use it for personal use.

Comment: @FarhanAnam Why would you use this and not some better one that is not copyrighted? This is probably the worst shader ball you can use, not a lot of work or though was put into it.