# What methods can be used to cut irregular shaped holes in flat beveled surfaces with clean topology?

Tags: topology, bevel

How do I fill these empty areas (left image) with no distortion(right image)?

I tried deleting all the faces and edges and then filling it which gave me a smooth flat surface around the holes but that method resulted in hard lines where the flat surface meets the bevel (the blue arrow), I want it to be a smooth transition (green arrow). I've tried marking that edge smooth and auto smooth with no avail. I'm having the best luck with the Subsurf modifier but I need better topology for that method to work well. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

[image: topology]

[image: smooth bevel]

[image: wireframe]

Here's the file:

[image]

Comment: Modelling these with [Proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) is the way to go

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try redoing it so that link should be useful.

Comment: I obviously have a lot to learn about modeling. I'm going to try the HardOps and Box Cutter tools.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you (maybe post your blend file?) but I recently learned about the Offset Edges plugin (needs to be downloaded and installed from file).  This works something like the way I would expect the "Shrink/Fatten" tool to work with a loop of edges--it will extrude them (or duplicate them, or move them) inwards or outwards in a way that does not distort the outline of the loop.

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges

How you might use that here, in a sample file that is maybe a little like your example.

1. The face to be created is between the top edge of the cylinder and the surrounding square edge.

[image]

2. Since these are two separate edge loops, we will offset each of them separately.  First the square edge, using Mesh-->Edges-->Offset Edges-->Extrude

[image]

3. Then offset the circle loop using the same command:

[image]

4. Now we can fill our remaining face, either using Mesh-->Faces-->Fill or Mesh-->Edges-->Bridge Edge Loops:

[image]

5. Et voila, the ugly triangle topology of the filled flat face does not impact the edges (in this case) because it is "buffered" by a margin of proper topology.

[image]

How this may work out in your case is hard to say for certain, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried this but it just makes for a weird transition. Looks like bevels are tricky - I'm looking at this post here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39424/glossy-reflections-and-smooth-shading?rq=1