# Best modeling workflow for painting textures

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, workflow

I know how to model, however, would it be easier to texture everything with a shape (cube, sphere, etc.) or with a plane that is mirrored? I haven't found any answers online.

Can someone please help me on which modeling technique would be best for texturing and materials? I love using the plane because you only have to worry about a couple vertices meanwhile if you model with a cube it would be doubled but for some reason I feel using a cube would be better with texturing because if something is mirrored it would look exactly the same on the opposite side, and sometimes I wouldn't want that.

Comment: Are you asking what is the best method for modeling to make texture painting easiest?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating materials for others, it is a common convention to test them on a shader ball. See this question: [Cycles advanced shader ball?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21807/cycles-advanced-shader-ball)

However, if you already have a mesh, it is best to test the material on it. The reason is that only the simplest materials are 100% mesh-independent, the rest have to be adjusted to the mesh, for example the depth of subsurface scattering depends on the scale of the mesh.

Comment: Ok I guess I could play around with a plane that is mirrored versus a shaped mesh (cube, sphere) and see which one would look better. But I just feel for some reason if I use a plane that's mirrored it would be identical on the other side and we all know that objects in real life are not always 100% identical on both sides. I'm asking this because I made a machete and one side I want writing and I feel if I start making a texture it would mirror it to the other side. As well as I would want different blood splatters, scratches, etc.

Comment: Test on the real machete. If you run into any problems, then you can ask about them separately.

Comment: But if I test it on my model, which is a mirrored plane, wouldn't it be exactly the same on the other side? Since I only want writing on 1 side is that not possible?

Comment: Whether the writing appears on both sides, depends on a lot of factors (did you use a mirror modifier, or the simple mirroring, how you did your uv unwrapping...). Don't worry, just try it :)

Comment: I used a mirror modifier and I already applied it. I haven't done anything with materials or textures first as I came here to ask the question first before screwing over my first good model.

Comment: If you already applied it and there is no overlap in the uv-unwrapping, then the text will not be mirrored. Don't be afraid to "screw up" your model, just make a backup copy if you are not sure that you can go back. The more models you screw up, the better you get :)

Comment: I never made a UV map yet I only made the model as I didn't want to mess anything up and do some research to make a really realistic material. For the blade I was planning on having scratches and blood splatters on it. But now that you said since its applied then it wouldn't affect the other side. I got my question answered thank you so much! So many tutorials used a plane with a mirror and I always wondered if they apply a texture would it be exactly symmetrical.

Comment: If your question was answered, you should accept the answer. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers