# Why am I getting this shadow on the top of my pocket watch?

Tags: modeling

This is driving me crazy. I've tried a bunch of lighting setups and the top is always dark like that. I think it's a shadow. I'm using a glossy material set to gold. Any help would really be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The lighter part is a reflection. It's simply brighter than everything else because of that. What's that plane that's over everything for?

Comment: That is the reflection of the panel you have on top. Lighting glossy materials (like gold) you have to put special attention to the reflections, since those are going to appear all over your object. see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/make-a-gold-reflective-object

Comment: The panel over it is an emission plane. I'll check out that link thanks.