# Why is the gold color code not used for Gold Materials

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I am looking at how to create a realistic looking gold material (for instance for ingots). So I am looking at a "pure gold" material. When I google I find this `#FFD700` hex value for the [color gold](http://colors.findthedata.com/l/641/Gold). This is a very saturated color of red and green (and NO blue). When I use that color for a simple glossy shader then I get this image. Somehow this color does not feel right ...

[image: glossy material FFD700]

I also found a [gold material](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/38983) at blend swap.

[image]

The shader is much more complex and a mix of colours is used (mixing forecolor and middle color and then mixing again with a back color).

Can someone explain this? Why this mixing of colors? And why is the Gold color code (`#FFD700`) not being used in this shader setup? Most people use a color with some blue in it.

How to construct a realistic gold shader? And what color to be used?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/make-a-gold-reflective-object

Comment: Gold in real life is quite tricky. As any highly reflective material it will take the color of whatever is surrounding it.  try adding some warm yellow to the light source. Here's a link that might give you some ideas: http://foto-stage.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-photograph-gold-with-different.html

Comment: @poor @ iKlsR♦ I have edited my question because you think my question has been asked before. I feel the edited question has not been asked before

Comment: @JanScherders I'd recommend: please roll it back to the 'original state' and ask a new one, which only addresses your *blendswap material issue* (good practice in my opinion). For a long time I've also struggled with duplicates here - However a *duplicate is not that bad* you might believe. It keeps this site clean and probably helps google finding the original question. Consider this site is run by people who like to use blender and volunteer their time and knowledge to solve 'general' issues and not a support site to fix 'personal' issues. BTW: gandalf's answer is simple and looks awesome.

Comment: ok, thanks @Poor I will do that. Any other recommendations ?Because I want to be a "good" member of this site

Comment: @JanScherders Great! I think this could be a good [meta question](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/), but I would examine first if this question is already asked before ;) Good luck!