# How come this face is curved?

Tags: modeling

This [existing answer's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43034/66364) sample file has a stage (I don't know what it is called) which seem to have 3 faces, but the middle one is curved.
[image]

I had learnt a way to create a stage like that on YouTube, but the procedure was:

- Add a plane
- Extrude one edge perpendicularly
- Add a bevel between the two surfaces
- Use the mouse wheel to create lots of angled surfaces.

So, mine looks like this. Notice that there are many narrow faces in between.
[image]

I wonder how the person created the same stage with only three faces.

Comment: Hello :). It's probably done with the *Bevel modifier*. It works the same, but doesnt show the added edges in the 3D viewport.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ Yeah. I got the same result when I tried that after reading your comment. Thanks.