# Metallic BSDF shader is always black

Tags: materials, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, gltf, pbr

I'm trying to model a textured and anodized aluminum material (think Apple MacBook). I'm using the Principled BSDF node because my end target is a glTF for display in the browser. Whatever I do, when setting metallic to 1, it always comes out black (both in Blender, and when rendering with three.js/WebGL in the browser).

I tried to duplicate some of the examples [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42877/how-to-build-a-shader-for-anodized-aluminium), and I get the same result. I believe the issue is something to do with not having the correct light sources or scenes to reflect, but I've tried variations of environment maps and actual scenes with various types of lights, and I never get anything other than solid black/dark grey.

[Here's the .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/DBo8bSlG/)

[image: metallic material rendering black]
[image: shader nodes]
[image: full Blender window]

Comment: First make sure that you are viewing the object in material preview shading or in rendered preview shading. Don't cut the images so tight. The information to help you is on the interface.

Comment: What color do you expect to see? Can you show your world shader?

Comment: @susu The first image I added was a render, but I just added a full window screenshot.

Comment: @Carlo Maybe you're on to something, my world surface was just set to a dark grey. Lightening it definitely lightens the model. Still no textures or highlights, though.

Comment: I see you tagged this question `glTF`.  Do you need this metal material to be compatible with glTF export?  Because that will [place some restrictions](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html) on the shader graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable screen space reflections. Answers vary depending on the render engine you are using, please always specify what you are using

[image]