# Issue with glass materials; these look blackned or are copying the background colour like a mirror

Tags: rendering, materials

An image worths more than 1000 words.
[image]

The water seems to be reflecting mostly the colour of the background but not too much the lights.

Basically, i'm trying to do this:

[image]

But i don't know what's happening. I stopped doing the tutorial because of this, tried a lot of things with the material imput, but nothing has changed.

(I'm doing this tuto, btw)
https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-a-realistic-fruit-splash

So... what i' doing wrong?

EDIT: Did it again with a mesh in the background (inside a cube). Not solving my problem at all :/

[image]

Still looks like some kind of onyx material, but nothing at all like water.

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/make-a-gold-reflective-object

Comment: But isn't supposed to be that way. I used to do that kind of stuff, working with fluid simulation and stuff, and the water was "visible" with every background, now it looks like some kind of weird mirror that is almost everything black.

Comment: Please post your render settings or the blend file.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4385" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4385/)

Comment: I haven't looked at the tutorial, so I can't say for sure what's going on. Nor can I find any attempts at a water material in your .blend. Two things come to mind though. 1. The shader isn't everything. The lighting is just as important, and with all black environment, you may have a really hard time getting _anything_ to look the way you want. 2. Less important, but not irrelevant, The _Glossy BSDF_ has a default IOR of 1.45. This is some kind of compromise-catch-all setting. For proper pure water set it to 1.33.

Comment: I just followed everything that was said in the tutorial, isn't suposed to be like that, i used to do water sim in the past, and it didn't ended like this. BTW, about the blend.file with no material, maybe the blend.file i send didn't have the material, but anyways, everytime i put the glass material in it, i only got that mirror/onyx thing. PD: No matter if changing the IOR from 1.45 to 1.33, is almost nothing, still, there's no transparency. And yes, i did put the correct IOR (see the first image), in the third image i forgot that, but still is 80% the same.

Comment: Here is the one with the texture already added (Sorry about the other one that didn't have the texture, i forgot about it :S) :  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4405" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4405/)