# Glow effect of Gold

Tags: lighting

I'd like to make a golden crown in 2.8 Blender which flies on top of a logo, as soon as it settles on the final position looks glowing or shining.

It's supposed to look like the color of the gold inside shines facing to the camera.

I tried to set a spot behind the crown, facing to the camera, the inside get's brighter but it doesn't transmits to the outside.

[Make a gold reflective object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15683/make-a-gold-reflective-object)

I used the first tutorial for the surface and a square shaped light.

Comment: I think you should look more into lighting the object in different angles than adding emission to a metallic shader

Answer (score 2):

Maybe add an emission node to the crown material, where you control the strength based on the location. You will have to also use a mix shader.

---

**Edit 1:** This is what I meant. Here I have a cube where the emission node is applied and mixed with the gold as per your example. The where the mix-factor is 0 (meaning only take the emission node). You could change this factor throughout the animation to slowly change, e.g. start the factor at 1 (100% gold), then animate through to a value you are happy with e.g. 0.4 (40% gold, 60% emission).

Since emission is very strong and will likely take away any details in your crown maybe only have small parts of your crown (or other objects) able to emit light and the rest staying pure gold. I hope this helps.

[image]

---

**Edit 2**: You are definitely after volumetric lighting then. Create a Cube around you scene, Add a material to your cube, delete the surface shader and add in a the Principled Volume shader. Reduce the density and now your lights should look like they are impacted by dust or fog in the scene.

[image]

NB this is rendered using Cycles with a denoiser in composition, using a density of 0.1 and a 10000W spot light.

[image]

The blender file I used is here: [image]

Comment: Can you help me a little more specific? I'm kinda new to it and need to know where to add the nodes and how to use it.. If you look at a beamer you see a little bit of light glowing in front of it maybe dust or else that add's that effect.

Comment: Edited for you. BTW If you are wanting dust etc, then look up volumetric lights

Comment: Good this means the cube glosw on the object? The idea is like this: A light shines through the crown, and then you can see somehow rays of lights shining in front of the crown.. Just like when u have a little fog or dust in front of a beamer and you can see the light rays in front

Comment: Hope this is more like it. I just added the volumetric lighting as an example.